# 2005 ford free star v6 front wheel drive

Tags: hvac

I have a problem with my A/C where it blows air fine in the rear but it wont blow in the front dash only by the feet and i noticed when i disconnect the battery everything works fine ontil it just stops working has anyone run into the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Air direction is controlled by a "mode" door and actuator. The actuator (motor) opens and closes doors to redirect airflow. Seems like it's working at startup and then defaulting to the floor position. Check a shop manual for diagnostic steps. If i remember correctly (which isn't a given) these older systems used vacuum motors to open/close the doors. If so, check for a vacuum leak in one of the lines or a leaking vacuum motor.